# Plotting the slope field of an implicit solution to an ODE

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a slope field for the given problem

```
sol = Flatten[DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^3/x^3 + y[x]/x + 1, y[x], x]]
initvalues2 = {{0, 0}, {-1, 3}, {3, 3}}
StreamPlot[{sol}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, VectorPoints -> initvalues2, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[initvalues2]}]
```

But I get the message

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

However, if I do a regular [Wolfram alpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5By%27%5Bx%5D%20%3D%3D%20y%5Bx%5D%5E3%2Fx%5E3%20%2B%20y%5Bx%5D%2Fx%20%2B%201%2C%20y%5Bx%5D%2C%20x%5D) of that ODE, I get a slope field, but the command is unknown.

Then I tried to plot the gradient of this solution, with C=1:

```
 Plot[Evaluate[
  Grad[ArcTan[(-1 + (2 y[x])/x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3] + 
     1/3 Log[1 + y[x]/x] - 1/6 Log[1 - y[x]/x + y[x]^2/x^2] == 
    1 + Log[x], y[x]]], {x, -3.2, 3.2}]
```

However, that also gave an empty plot.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to plot a slope field for the given problem

You could try `StreamPlot`. I do not understand why you actually trying to solve the ODE to use `StreamPlot`. The whole idea is that one does not need to solve the ode analytically to use `StreamPlot`. It plots the solution curves numerically. No need to solve the ode analytically at all. It will give solution curves to ode's that can't even be solved analytically, since `StreamPlot` is numerical method.

```
f[x_, y_] := y^3/x^3 + y/x + 1
p1 = StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 5},
  Frame -> False,
  Axes -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"},
  StreamPoints -> {{{{-1, 3}, Red}, {{3, 3}, Green}, Automatic}}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to one solution

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^3/x^3 + y[x]/x + 1, y[-1] == 3}, 
       y, {x, -1, 4}];
Plot[sol[x], {x, -1, 4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the second

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^3/x^3 + y[x]/x + 1, y[3] == 3}, 
   y, {x, 1, 4}];
Plot[sol[x], {x, 1, 4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that initial conditions `{0,0}` do not seem to be valid IC for this ode. (singularity).

Comment: Thanks Nasser. I saw you use NDsolve, and not Dsolve. Is that why it didn't work in my attempt?

Comment: @Vangsnes I only used `NDSolve` just to show that its results agrees with `StreamPlot` ! That is all. it was an extra credit. You do not need to use `NDSolve` nor `DSolve` to obtain solution curves. That is what I meant. The colored stream lines are the two specific solution curves for two initial conditions you had.

Comment: Sure, but you have to solve the ODE first using DSolve or NDSolve?

Comment: @Vangsnes I might be misunderstanding something.  You are looking to plot the solution curves for the ODE you showed, right?  Is this your goal, or you want something additional to that?   As I mention, to plot solution curves, just use `StreamPlot`. That is all., No need to solve anything, Just need the ode in the form $y'(x)=f(x,y)$ and you just need to know $f(x,y)$.   Your ode is already in this form. Just plugin $f(x,y)$ into the StreamPlot command as shown above.

Comment: Yes, this is correct you say,